# A Term for a Location Where a Person has Stopped or Idled for an allocated length of time

Tags: grammar, word-usage, terminology, programming

I am developing a *Geographic Information System* where GPS coordinates are gathered and analyzed in a server. I have a module where I collect coordinates/points in a map where a person has stopped for an allocated length of time.

So, my question is what **term/word** can I used for those points (which will be equivalent to a location) ***"where a person has stopped or has idled [for an allocated length of time]"***? So far I have been using the word "**Idled Location**" for this which I feel to be grammatically incorrect. I think '*Idled*' describes the '*Location*' here. So the word must mean a Location where I have been idled for some time.

Comment: "Waypoint" (or "way-point" or "way point", depending on your religion) is sometimes used to refer to an intermediate point on a route.

Comment: "idle point" has nice rhythm.

Comment: "idling point" or "idling location" might work. "Idle point" has a nice rhythm, but is less precise as it suggests that it is the point which was idle rather than the person.

Comment: @Dan Romik, "idling point" and "idling location" suffer from exactly the same ambiguity.

Comment: @Silenus I agree that "idling point" has the ambiguity issue, but "idle point" is worse, to me it reads like it _unambiguously_ says the wrong thing, but I suppose I could be wrong about that.

Comment: Is Idle Spot a good one?

Comment: ***loiter location***  for alliteration, or *loiter point* for something that trips off the tongue a little easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Idle Location* is grammatically correct. Some more ideas: *Idle Area*, *Idle Zone*, *Rest Spot*, *Resting Point*, *Break Point*

Comment: Is 'Idle Spot' a good one?

Answer (score 1):

Consider **intermission point**. [Dictionary.com defines intermission](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/intermission) as "a period during which action temporarily ceases."